# SSIS error metadata mismatch when running in Control M

Tags: ssis

I have an SSIS (2008) package in which I am populating an existing column in the file with a field that has a date if a certain condition is met.  I did a convert in my query for the date (went from date time to yyyymmdd). When I run the package on my desktop, it runs fine, the date is in the file's column when the condition is met otherwise 0's appear in the column. It is only when I run the package via Control M that I get a metadata mismatch error and vs_is broken error messages and the package fails.  Why does the package run fine on my desktop but not on the test server?

Comment: There ought to be more error messages beyond vs_isbroken. Pop some screenshots of what your package looks like and the command Contrl M is issuing to run the SSIS package please

Comment: I will have to post tomorrow when I log on at work.  The first error message is a metadata mismatch and the next message is vs_is broken.  I should have added that the condition for the date to be put in the file is in the script task (vb) do I need to do a date conversion for the field that is populating the date even though I did a conversion in the query.